# Transportation statistics for Grand Central Terminal

Tags: data-request, transportation

[Grand Central Terminal](http://www.grandcentralterminal.com/info/eventplanning) reports serving 750K people daily.

Is there an MTA dataset for that, or at least a way to approximate that with hourly granularity?

Answer (score 1):

This won't capture people passing through for shopping or eating, but it will capture the bulk of traffic: http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html